# Different types of mechanic jacks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, work, applied-physics

I need help. **I would like to know:** **what the differences between the jacks illustrated below are and with which jack a car can be lifted easiest (according to the answer sheet it is jack **B**).**

**My preliminary-knowledge on the topic:** I know how a car jack works in a general sense, I know about the principle of trading Force for distance.

**My perception:** It seems to me that **A** shouldn't be able to work at all as it looks like the two rods aren't connected to each other. Or do I get it wrongly? I can't see the difference between **B** and **C**.

I have tried to find out schematics of the jack illustrations below on the web by typing in different word-combies, but, unfortunately, I haven't managed to find yet. If one does know a source, that's also always welcome!

**Note:** I received the questions exactly as I present them here from the organization I got them from. Therefore, I suffer from not being able to provide more context and specifications. I am only being able to provide my assumptions based on my preliminary knowledge.

Thanks a lot in advance for your assistance!

[image]

Comment: What do the different shades mean?

Comment: That isn't given, however, it appears to me that it are the screws present in jacks, especially since there is a difference in the direction in which the shade-lines point in illustration A, which indicates a possibility of the presence of screw threads.

Comment: But with that, the side of B with the handle doesn't have any threads, so shouldn't B do nothing when you crank the handle then? Or is the right part actually connected to the left part?

Comment: I believe A is a solid rod with opposite screws on either side of the middle.  B has a screw in the left side of the shaft but just smooth on the right.  C has the same pitch screw all the way across.

Comment: @ AaronStevens: I wonder about that too, brainstorming so far, I also have that assumption. Say, it is connected, than it wouldn't do anything too, right? @JoelKeene: I have never seen two horizontally connected screws with opposite  screw threads. That wouldn't turn, would it?

Comment: @Englishterian the black pieces are hinged pretty much everywhere they make a turn, so they are free to move however they wish.  So if you turn the screw in one direction, one side moves one way, the other side moves the other way.  For B, the side that doesn't have threads doesn't move, but I think the problem assumes that there is a bearing or something so that the rod doesn't slide either.  In other words, only the left side moves

Comment: I guess we can all agree this diagram needs way more context and specifications

Comment: So, do I get it correctly if I rephrase it like this: for case B, the right (white) screw that doesn't have threads can only turn around its own axis and can NOT move horizontally with respect to the black rods; so the point where the black rods make contact with the white rod does never change. However, the white rod is so tightly pressed against the left screw, that the left screw start to turn (in the opposite direction) when you crank the handle attached to the white rod. And when that happens, the jack moves up?

Comment: @AaronStevens I agree, however, the struggle is that I received the questions exactly as I present them here from the organization I got them from. Therefore, I suffer from not being able to provide more context and specifications.

Comment: The term you are looking for to search is 'scissor jack', and they're all (B) in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the threads involved have the same pitch, we can say that one turn of the crank in case A (two nuts), will move the jack up twice as much as in case B (one nut). In case C, the jack would not do any lifting (thanks to @tfb for pointing that out).

This, of course, means that, for any given state (height) of the jack, the applied force (required to move the load up) in case A has to be twice bigger than in case B.

So, it is just another example the force-distance trade-off.

Comment: If the shading indicates the direction of the threads (and if I read the shading right: the image resolution is marginal) then C doesn't work at all: it will just slowly wind the threaded rod out of the jack (and then fail catastrophically when it's wound out of the far end)

Comment: @tfb That would depend on the threads on the nuts, which are not shown. I assume that we are presented with three functional jacks, so the nuts should have appropriate threads to make all of them function properly.

Comment: It wouldn't.  You can't make a nut move differently on a bolt by changing its thread: one turn moves the nut one thread-pitch and that's all you can do.  In practice what scissor jacks do is B of course.

Comment: @tfb Agree. Thanks for your feedback. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks @tfb , I have also tried searching on "scissor jack (- types), unfortunately without results leading to  different types. I would be thankful if you have a source to provide.

Comment: @Englishterian I assume you meant to address your question to me (V.F.) - if not, you can disregard this comment. I did not use any particular source that contained the answer. In general, when we turn the crank once, the rod advanced into the nut by the length of one thread pitch, which squeezes the jack horizontally by the same length, which causes it to extend vertically. If we have two nuts, both squeezing the jack by one pitch, one turn of the crank will squeeze and lift the jack twice more, which means that twice as much energy per turn will be needed and, hence, twice as much force.

Comment: @Englishterian You can check out this video (at least the first part) to get some basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LsH5OaorXE.

Comment: No, it was actually meant for tfb. However, thanks for what you wrote as it made stuff more clear for me. I was just being busy with typing the following to you, which I STILL would like to know @V.F: Thanks for your answer! I know that the first nut is located leftmost in picture B. Where is the second? And I still have difficulties understanding the anatomy of picture A and B, since they look different (the split, the white part at the side of the handle) than the standard scissor jack I know. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @Englishterian The B does not have the second nut, which is typical for real jacks of this design. The A has two nuts, one on each side, but, since the threads are opposite on the two halves of the rod (indicated by different patterns),  when we turn the crank, the rod goes into one nut and out of the other, resulting in squeezing the jack (or expanding when it is lowered) from both sides and, therefore at twice the speed or twice distance per turn.

Comment: @Englishterian My 'source' was really just all the ones I've ever seen, which is anecdotal of course...